# Save ping results to text file with Computer name

Tags: batch-file, ping

I'd like to use a variation of the following batch script to save the results of a ping test to a folder on the network with the computer name appended to the file name or somewhere in the results.

```
ping www.google.com -n 1000 > pinglog.txt
type pinglog.txt
```

I need to perform some diagnostics on all computers of a network to determine whether a connection stability issue is router related, internet related or localised to just one of the computers.

The batch file will be stored on the network at \\192.168.1.254\ICT\Scripts, and I would like the log files saved to that location with the computer name added so that I can determine which PC the results belong to (eg. pinglog-reception.txt).

Can this be done?  If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this for different servers, then:

```
server=www.google.com
ping %server% -n 1000 > \\192.168.1.254\ICT\Scripts\%server%.txt
type \\192.168.1.254\ICT\Scripts\%server%.txt
```

If you want to do this for different querying computers on your own network, then see the other answer. You will need to use the network name for the file:

```
ping www.google.com -n 1000 > \\192.168.1.254\ICT\Scripts\pinglog-%COMPUTERNAME%.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `%COMPUTERNAME%` environment variable:

```
ping www.google.com -n 1000 > pinglog-%COMPUTERNAME%.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pathping
```

would seem to be better suited to this than `ping`.